# this tool does not support the current operating system

Tags: sharepoint-server

when I tried to install the prerequisite of sharepoint 2016, it does not do and retures the error "this tool does not support the current operating system." I have SQL 2016 SP1 installed.

Comment: what's the current operating system ?

Comment: do you have internet connection on the server? and also what Windows server version you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint 2016 can be installed on

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard or Datacenter
- Windows Server 2016 Standard or Datacenter

And with SQL Server

- The 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RTM

For more details check [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx)

Also, based on this official article [SharePoint 2013/2016 and SQL Server 2016 Supportability with SSRS fun facts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ronalg/2016/06/13/sharepoint-20132016-and-sql-server-2016-supportability-with-ssrs-fun-facts/)! SharePoint is working with **SQL 2016 – n** that mean it's not supported with `SQL 2016 SP1`

Comment: I saw the disk requirement that indicates OS 80g and another 100g. I don't have so much space on my disk, could this be the reason of failure?

Comment: what's your curent disk capacity ?